# ckeditor instance already exists after ajax + jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I use JQuery for CKeditor.
I have several textarea for this. 
Name of textarea may be different at the moment of content generation.

By this, I use classes instead of ID:

```
$('.ckedit').ckeditor();
```

After AJAX content reload, i have error in conclose:
*The instance *something* already exists*

I know, i can use destroy method for Ckeditor:

```
if (CKEDITOR.instances['textarea_name']) {
  CKEDITOR.instances['textarea_name'].destroy();
}
```

but i cant do it, because name/id of textarea may be several at the moment.

How i can resolve this problem? Thanks and sorry for my english:)

Answer (score 0):

I try this code and works for me, when I have an UpdatePanel with a CkEditor in it:

aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <textarea></textarea>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnGo" runat="server" OnClick="btnGo_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ReplaceWithCkEditor();
});

function pageLoad() {
    ReplaceWithCkEditor();
}

function ReplaceWithCkEditor() {
    $('textarea').ckeditor();
}
```

Microsoft Ajax framework runs `pageLoad` function after UpdatePanel done it works. and then I replace textarea with CkEditor.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.
I resolve this problem.

Before

```
$('.ckedit').ckeditor();
```

need insert:

```
jQuery.each(CKEDITOR.instances, function(){
     eval("CKEDITOR.instances."+this.name+".destroy(true)");
});
```

Comment: Guys, i have a good news. After install last version Ckeditor (4 ver.) code for destroy instances no need to. :)

Answer (score 0):

You add the class wysiwyg at your textarea and you call this function.when you will convert new textarea use this function for convert the news elements textarea with this class.

```
CKEDITOR.basePath += 'ckeditor/';
CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '/ckeditor/contents.css' ;      
function addWysiwyg()
{
    var eldata = $(document).find('.wysiwyg');

    console.log(eldata);
    var config = {};
    $(eldata).each(function(){
       CKEDITOR.replace(this, config);
       $(this).removeClass('wysiwyg');
    });
}
```